# No scroll in iframe. Access child elements inside ref (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iframe

I am using an iframe, and I want to get the height of the content so my iframe do not get a scroll, but the height I am getting is wrong. Because of this I want to try something out: access an element inside the iframe and get the height of that. I am using useRef on my iframe. So how can I access elements inside my ref?

```
const ref = useRef(null);
const [height, setHeight] = useState(null);

...

<iframe
  ref={ref}
  onLoad={() => {
    setHeight(ref?.current?.scrollHeight); // this is wrong height
   // want to access an element inside the ref, e.g. an element with an id and use something like .getBoundingClientRect().height
  }}
  ...
/>
```

Thank you for any help!

Comment: try `ref?.current?.contentWindow.document.body.scrollHeight` also you might need to append "px" to end of that string

Comment: Thank you for that input! I forgot to mention that I have tried that already, and unfortunately I did not manage to make it work. I got some error saying `SecurityError: Permission denied to access property "document" on cross-origin object`